# Java Regex with underscore

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s*");
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(2));
} else {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

And when i use this:

```
HEY_YO NICE GUYHERE
```

It shows output: Not found.
How to get a string with underscore? (_)

Input:

```
HEY_YO NICE GUYHERE
```

And i want to output:

```
Found: HEY_YO
```

Comment: I don't think you need to escape `\w`. And what pattern are you exactly trying to match ?

Comment: And it's called an "underscore". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `matcher.find()` you can specify only what you want to capture :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "HEY_YO NICE GUYHERE";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(0));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
Found: HEY_YO
```

Comment: Any idea what's wrong with OPs regex? According to [some random documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html), `\w` oight to have included the underscore.

Comment: @RadLexus - He is actually printing the wrong group. He should pring group1

Comment: @RadLexus - But his regex has a flaw. It is not looking for `"_"`.

Comment: First: he would print the wrong group but it prints "not found". Second: `\w` **includes** `_`. I made sure to look that up before asserting...

Comment: @RadLexus - Yes . \w includes `_`. I never denied it. I am saying that He is not **specifically** looking for a word with `_`. Next I am not sure what you are trying to say

Comment: @inshi666 - `matches()` looks to match the entire String. `find()` on the other hand tries to find a matching String. So, you just ahve to specify what you want to find

Comment: my regex, idk why.

Comment: @inshi666 - Your regex says `Found: NICE`. Did you try to print group 1?. BTW did you try to print `group(1)`?

Answer (score 2):

i think you are not passing **"HEY_YO NICE GUYHERE"** as input because for this input your code will produce **"Found: NICE"** as output.To get the output you want 
replace

```
System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(2));
```

with

```
System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(1));
```